# RecyclerView displaying last nested array items form a parent array, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I have implemented RecyclerView in my app with **Kotlin** using **Refrofit, MVVM, DataBinding, Coroutines.** The problem is i have some nested arrays which i want to parse using viewModel. Here is the structure of the api: [image]

What i want is to parse the inner services **arrays** inside the categoryService array.
The xml items layout is like this:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="services"
        type="com.techease.fitness.models.categoryServices.Service" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tenDP"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_card_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/tenDP"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivService"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="@dimen/tenDP"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image_24"
            bind:avatar="@{services.attachment}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/user_name"
            android:text="@{services.title}"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/user_name"
            android:text="@{services.duration}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my existing viewModel which only returns the last item from categoryService[last]  and displaying the services items.

```
 private lateinit var job: Job
    private val catServices = MutableLiveData<List<Service>>()
    val discoverServices: MutableLiveData<List<Service>>
        get() = catServices

    fun discoverServices(context: Context) {
        job = CoroutinesIO.ioThenMain(
            {
                repository.discoverServices(context)
            }, {
                for (i in 0 until it!!.data.categoryServices.size) {
                    for (services in 0 until it.data.categoryServices.get(i).services.size) {
                        catServices.value = it.data.categoryServices.get(i).services
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

i have nested for loops in viewModel which is parsing the target array correctly but only displaying the last item service array. Here is the recyclerView implementation:

```
 

     val apiRepository = ApiRepository()
            factory = DiscoverViewModelFactory(apiRepository)
    
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(DiscoverServiceViewModel::class.java)
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
            viewModel.discoverServices(this)
            viewModel.discoverServices.observe(this, Observer { services ->
                rvFeatured.also {
                    it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
                    it.setHasFixedSize(true)
                    if (services != null) {
                        it.adapter = DiscoverServicesAdapter(services, this)
                    }
                }
            })
```

And here is the adapter which is fully binded:

```
    private val services: List<Service>,
    private val listenerHomeServices: DiscoverServicesClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DiscoverServicesAdapter.ServicesViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = services.size


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ServicesViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.custom_discover_layout,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServicesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.recyclerViewServicesBinding.services = services[position]

    }

    class ServicesViewHolder(
        val recyclerViewServicesBinding: CustomDiscoverLayoutBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(recyclerViewServicesBinding.root)}
```

Again i want to parse the nested service array, but currently only the last categoryService[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMpvN.png) service array items are displayed by recyclerView.  Hope this make sense.

Comment: your code seems to be fine have yo check to log out services list in recycler adapter to check if the correct list is passed or its passing just the last item

Comment: in serviceCategory[1] i have 5 service items, which are displaying by the recyclerView.....Skipping serviceCategory[0]

Comment: that means you have some bug in loop logic of discover method

Comment: not in loop as i debuged it step by step, there is some bug in adapterNotify may be